# pip package error after uploading to test.pypi.org

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

I have created a pip package as below

[image]

my setup.py file

```
import setuptools

with open('README.md') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="calculator_py",
    version="0.0.1",
    scripts=['scripts/calculate.py'],
    author="xxxxxxx",
    author_email="xxxx@gmail.com",
    description="",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url="",
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Programming Language :: Python',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Operating System :: OS Independent',

],
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'calculate=calculator.scripts.calculate:main',
    ],
}

)
```

I have uploaded this package to https://test.pypi.org

after I have installed package using

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ calculator_py
```

I have checked package using

```
pip list
```

when I try to import this package it gives me below error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calculator_py'

calculate.py file

```
class calculate:

def __init__(self):
    pass

def add(self, arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

def sub(self, arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 - arg2

def mul(self, arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 * arg2

def div(self, arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 / arg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
     calculate()
```

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: please fix your indentation.

Comment: `calculator_py` is only the name of the distribution, you have no modules or packages named that so there's nothing to import. Run `pip show -f calculator_py` to see what files are installed. `calculate` executable should be available: check it with `which calculate`. BTW `calculate=calculator.scripts.calculate:main` will not work because there's no module `calculator.scripts.calculate` in your package.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a `packages=['scripts']` inside your `setuptools.setup`, eg.

```
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    packages=['scripts'],
    ...
)
```

Otherwise pip probably tries to *guess* it from `name="calculator_py"` and you don't have a package named `calculator_py`.

Comment: First, there is `scripts=['scripts/calculate.py'],` It'd be strange to add both `scripts` and `packages=['scripts'],`. Second, `pip` doesn't guess module names from package name.